# Reverse special charcters with Panda in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, python-2.7, lambda

Imagine I have a string like this in a column named A:

```
A00001-BL - A00002-BL
D00002-BL-D00003-BL
FA0003 -BL- FA0005-BL
```

Now I just want to reverse the numbers as below and put it in column B with lambda with panda in python or any alternative way:

```
A00002-BL - A00001-BL
D00003-BL-D00002-BL 
FA0005 -BL- FA0003-BL
```

I have more than 300000 rows with different characters and I have to apply this reversion on all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
df.A.str.replace(r'^(\w+\s*-\s*\w+)(\s*-\s*)(.*)$',r'\3\2\1')
```

Output:

```
0    A00002-BL - A00001-BL
1      D00003-BL-D00002-BL
2    FA0005-BL- FA0003 -BL
Name: A, dtype: object
```

For a explanation of the first regex string, see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/St9vkq/1). The second regex string just means that you reverse the three capture groups in the former.